# Avoiding multiple import in Kivy when calling a function from a different file

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I'm developing a small app using kivy and python3.6 (I'm still a beginner). I'm planning to separate the code in different files for clarity, however I have encountered a problem in a specific situation. I have made minimal working example to illustrate.

I have the following files:

- main.py
- main.kv
- module.py
- module.kv

Here a minimal code:

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
import module

Builder.load_file('module.kv')

class MainApp(App):
    pass

def function():
    print('parent function')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

main.kv:

```
CallFunction
```

module.py:

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class CallFunction(Button):
    def call_function(self):
        from main import function
        function()
```

module.kv:

```
<CallFunction>:
    id : parent_button
    text: 'Call parent button'
    on_press: self.call_function()
```

So the problem is that when I run this code, I receive a warning

> The file /home/kivy/python_exp/test/module.kv is loaded multiples times, you might have unwanted behaviors.

**What works**:

- If the function I want to call is part of the main app class, there is no problem
- If the function is part of the module.py there is no problem
- If the function is part of another module, there is no problem

**What doesn't work**
I cannot call a function which is in the *main.py*. If I use the import the function as the beginning of module.py, kivy has a weird behavior and call everything twice. Calling within this *call_function* allows to have a proper interface, but I get the warning that the file has been loaded multiple time.

There are easy workarounds, I'm well aware of that, so it's more about curiosity and understanding better how the imports in kivy works. Is there a way to make it work?

I wanted to use the main.py to initialize different things at the startup of the app. In particular I wanted to create an instance of another class (not a kivy class) in the main.py and when clicking on the button on the interface, calling a method on this instance.

Thanks :)

Comment: If you are using multiple kv, rather than build them in your main.py you should include them in your main.kv at the beginning.

Comment: Good point, but what is the difference? I don't really understand. Actually I just tried that and it solved the issue of the multiple import... Could you maybe make it as an answer? (and maybe explain what's the difference between including another kv file and building another kv file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you import something from another python module the python virtual machine execute this module. In the **call_function** you import **function** from the **main** file so everytime you press the **CallFunction** the **module.kv** is loaded.

To solve this it is recommended to include the other kv files in your main kv file.

You can also move the import statement from the method to the top of the module file.

Comment: Importing a module only executes the module code if the module was not already imported once. It's not super clear in the documentation but [this page](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-import-system) which describes how things are imported states: "When a module is first imported, Python searches for the module and if found, it creates a module object [1], initializing it."

Answer (score 0):

Your kv file is loaded twice because the code is executed twice. This is due to how pythons module system works and kivy just realized that loading the kv twice is probably not what you want.

Generally python objects live in a namespace. So when a function in the module `foo` looks up a variable the variable is searched in the namespace of the module. That way if you define two variables `foo.var` and `bar.var` (in the modules `foo` and `bar` resp.) they don't clash and get confused for each other.

The tricky thing is that the python file you execute is special: It does not create a module namespace but the `__main__` namespace. Thus if you import the file you are executing as `__main__` it will create a whole new namespace with new objects and execute the module code. If you import a module that was already imported in the current session the module code is *not* executed again, but the namespace already created is made available. You don't even need two files for that, put the following in `test.py`:

```
print("hello!")
print(__name__)
import test
```

If you now execute `python test.py` you will see two `hello!` and once `__main__` and once `test`.

You can find more information on namespaces and how variable lookups works in python in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces).

Also if your `function` actually does some work and mutates an object that lives in main.py you might want to rethink the information flow. Often it is a good idea to bind the state and functions working on them together in classes and passing the objects then where they are called i.e. to `CallFunction` in your example.

Comment: Thanks for the further explaination. I think I was kind of aware of that but I couldn't make it work at first (the previous answer works fine) since the import executed the builder twice. It was more an issue with kivy than with the import I think.

Comment: The builder is executed twice: First when you execute the main.py file as `__main__` and then again when you import main as `main` module. If you move the import to the top of the file you still execute main.py twice (and should still get the error, but in a different "location" and probably hidden behind other initialisation messages). If you store state (lets say a list) in the main module, this will lead to hard-to-debug bugs because nothing throws errors or warnings. If you are not storing anything there the python side should "work fine".